# Trouble with characters in C

Tags: c, char, compiler-errors, fgetc

Why does this not compile? Cant see the error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *c;
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    if(f == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file");
    }

    while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        if(strcmp(c, " ") == 0) {
            printf(" ");
        } else if(strcmp(c, ":") == 0) {
            printf(":");
        } else if(strcmp(c, "@") == 0) {
            printf("@");
        } else if(strcmp(c, "\n") == 0) {
            printf("\n");
        } else {
            printf("Not a valid char");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "Cant see the error" ? You mean your compiler crashes as badly on this code that you even can't tell us what he is complaining about?

Comment: You must return an int, if you set the return type of main as int.

Comment: @crypto: if he's using a C99 compiler, there's an implicit `return 0;` statement right before the end of `main`, so he needn't type it explicitly (but, it's better if he does, I think)

Answer (score 11):

`fgetc` returns the char currently at the file pointer as an integer.

So `char *c;` should be `int c;`

and

```
if(strcmp(c, " ") == 0) {
```

should be

```
if(c == ' ') {
```

and similarly change other comparisons.

You can compact the comparisons as:

```
while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
    if(c == ' ' || c == ':' || c == '@' || c == '\n') {
        printf("%c",c);
    } else {
        printf("Not a valid char");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because a `char *` is not a `char`.

The `fgetc` function returns a character, not a string. That means that your entire group of `if` statements is wrong too. You should be doing simple things like:

```
if( c == ' ' ) {
} else if( c == ':' ) {
} ...
```

Comment: fgetc returns an int actually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fgetc() returns int, not char or char*.  Why is this important?  Because EOF is usually (always?) defined as -1.  If fgetc() returns EOF into an 8 bit char, it will be represented as 0xFF.  In some character sets this is a valid character. e.g. y-umlaut in ISO-8859-1.  Thus using

```
char c; // << this is wrong, use int
while((c = fgetc(aFile)) == EOF)
{
     // stuff
}
```

you cannot distinguish between end of file and one of the characters that can legitimately appear in the stream.

Comment: Why the down vote?  The code sample was to demonstrate how **not** to do it.  Please fully read the answer before down voting.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, fgetc returns an int not actually a string (So strcmp will fail).  My personally preferred though not really any different method of char comparison is to use a switch, and since you have several printing out the input character you might have something like:

```
while( (c = fgetc(f)) != EOF ) {
  switch( c )
  {
    case ' ':
    case ':':
    case '@':
    case '\n':
      printf( "%c", c );
      break;
    default:
      printf( "Not a valid char" );
  }
}
```

I have found this to be the easiest way, especially when you know you'll want to expand on your conditions later.  ( Say if you wanted to add: 'f', 'o', and 'r' )

Comment: fgetc returns an int, not a char